# XAMPP can't START to Running MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have been using the same XAMPP for a long time, and everything is fine. But today, MySQL does not want to do the `running` (`start`) process.

I have done a number of ways, such as restarting, removing `ibdata`, `aria_log`, then trying again. But the results still cannot be `running`, even `ibdata` and others that I deleted back to normal.

```
9:50:34 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
9:50:39 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Problem detected!
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Problem detected!
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL app...
10:04:17 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
10:04:20 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

What should I do? I really need help, I need to open `PhpMyadmin`

Comment: _Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!_ You look like you have TWO MySQL Servers installed and the Other one is being autostarted at boot time. Did you install WorkBench? That is the normal culprit. Or did you try manually installing MySQL before you found XAMPP

Comment: Are you Windows or a *nix

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I am a windows user.

Yes, that's right, I recently installed a workbench. I just found out that workbench had an impact in 'running' MySQL on Xampp.
Then what should I do? Is the disabling workbench is the solution?

Comment: It does not have an impact perse. It can install its own version of MySQL. That is what I think has happened. I suggest you uninstall WorkBench **(backup and databases you want to keep first)** and then reinstall it, making sure you DO NOT install MySQL with it ( I think its an option) The WorkBench will be able to see the XAMPP version of MySQL

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
10:04:16 PM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
```

3306 port is in use. try to change  Port number of Mysql Server from ini file (my.ini). Or perhaps another mysql process is already running

you can check if another instance of mysql is running by

```
ps -eaf | grep mysql
```

Comment: If 3306 is in use, it normally means 2 instances of MySQL and the other one is getting started at boot

Comment: normally but not necessarily (something else may be using 3306 as well).

Comment: :) [But not in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57415933/xampp-cant-start-to-running-mysql?noredirect=1#comment101314390_57415933) :)